# EXCEL: Auto number rows until value in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, sequential, autonumber

This is probably very easy, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'd like a formula for autonumbering rows based on the value in B1.
Starting from B1 id like to autonumber rows from 1 and down until the value defined in B1.

This need to be a formula, and not VBA beacuse of other technical obstacles  cannot solve.

I manage until I reach the defined value (blank) is returned, and the next row returns #VALUE because the calculation fails.

I have tried all the IF, IFS, <>"", <=, >=, AND, OR combinations I can think of.

How can I define this and avoid the #VALUE error.
The defined value in B1 will be a value ranging from 6 to 48

[image: screendump of result]

Would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: What is the formula you've used to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can use `SEQUENCE`:

Put `=SEQUENCE(B1,1,1,1)` in the cell below `Month`

The values will spill down - that means there have to be enough empty cells below the formula cell

This will create a numbered sequence --> number of rows is set via value in `B1`, one column, starting at 1